# Error expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, sintaxis

soy nuevo en programacion en c++ y estoy experimentando con codigos,estoy practicando para usar la libreria `fstream` y estoy haciendo un codigo simple para probarlo,el problema es que a la hora de compilar me sale el error del titulo,yo por lo que entiendo se que es un error de sintaxis antes del . pero no encuentro nada mal escrito,espero puedan ayudarme,aqui les dejo el codigo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int CANT=32;//todavia sin uso

struct alumno
{
string nombre;
int nota1;
int nota2;
int nota3;
double final;
string descripcion;
};




int main(){
char cadena [500];
ofstream fs("lista.txt");
int select;
cout<<"Lista de alumnos"<<endl;
cout<<"1=abrir lista de alumnos"<<endl;
cout<<"2=ingresar un alumno"<<endl;
cout<<"3=salir"<<endl;
cin>> select;

switch (select){


    case 1:{
        ifstream fe ("lista.exe");
        fe.getline(cadena,500);
        cout<<cadena<<endl;
    break;
    }
    
    case 2:{
        cout<<"nombre:"<<endl,cin>>alumno.nombre;
        cout<<"observaciones"<<endl,cin>>alumno.descripcion;
        cout<<"nota del primer trimestre:"<<endl,cin>>alumno.nota1;//en estas lineas tengo el error despues del .
        
    break;  
   }
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da cuando utilizas el **cin** e intentas ingresar un dato a "alumno.dat" (dat es algún dato que esta dentro de la estructura) sin haber declarado antes una variable de ese tipo.
Nunca declaraste una variable de tipo alumno donde almacenar el dato.

```
alumno yo;
cout<<"Nombre: "<<endl,cin>>yo.nombre;
```

Sería lo correcto, también soy nuevo experimentando con este lenguaje, espero te haya ayudado!